# Flutter - keeping Drawer after page navigation

Tags: flutter

I have a Drawer widget on main.dart. The Drawer works great on this page, but when I navigate to a different page, using code like below,  I lose the the drawer on the new page. Is there any recommended way to keep the drawer after navigating to a separate page?

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MessageEntryPage()));
```

I saw similar questions in stackoverflow but couldn't get an answer.

Comment: open drawer programmatically on new page by calling Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661319/3756408?

Comment: Thanks Darish, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

not use Navigator.push

instance of body change

for example

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  drawer: your drawer ,
  body:  // your Widget
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ), 
);
```

When we change the drawer, we use setState to change the widget on the body