# Flutter subclass Scaffold so I can ensure a Drawer and BottomNavigationBar are always present

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-appbar, flutter-scaffold, flutter-drawer

I have a `Flutter` app with sections that I can access from both a `BottomNavigationBar` and a `Drawer`. I have this working in a `Scaffold` at the root level of my app, and I then use `Navigator` widgets to create separate routes and stacks within each section. The `BottomNavigationBar` persists as I push new screens onto the stack, and these new screens will have their own `AppBar` and actions specific to those user journeys.

The problem is that I need the `Drawer` to be present on all of my screens, and setting a new `AppBar` in a `Scaffold` on individual screens removes the `Drawer` that I had set in my root level `Scaffold`.

How can I pass that `Drawer` through to all my screen `AppBar` instances? I don't want to create new `Drawer` instances over multiple widgets, so I should create a `Singleton` of the `Drawer` or even the entire `Scaffold`? What's the best practise here?

Comment: please reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659805/persisting-appbar-drawer-across-all-pages-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state management package. I suggest use provider packages or flutter_bloc so that you can get more out of flutter UI but be careful about their name and here is a doc link that is made by flutter team and will help you with all the state management package:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

This one is for bloc_flutter doc I couldn't find it on the previous link document: https://bloclibrary.dev