# Navigator operation requested a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter

I found the below error's explanation in this link: [Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator)
I tried to apply to my problem but I couldn't solve the problem.

When I click the button in the NavigationBar class, I got this error:

The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

```
void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    AppRouter appRouter = AppRouter(
      routes: AppRoutes.routes,
      notFoundHandler: AppRoutes.routeNotFoundHandler,
    );

    appRouter.setupRoutes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'abc',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      builder: (_, child) => AppView(
        child: child,
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.router.generator,
      );
  }
}

class AppView extends StatelessWidget {
  
final Widget child;
  
const AppView({@required this.child});
  
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [NavigationBar(), Expanded(child: child)],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: MaterialButton(
              child: Text(
                "Home",
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                AppRouter.router
                    .navigateTo(context, AppRoutes.saticilarRoute.route);
              },
            ),
          ),
           //TODO
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this problem occurred:

Any widget returned by the builder will be the parent of the navigator.

[image]

If you want the persistent navigation bar across all pages then you can use builder.

```dart
// Need to pass the child to navigation bar which is not a good solution
class NavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
const NavigationBar({Key key, this.child}: super(key:key))
final Widget child;

// Replace this
AppRouter.router.navigateTo(context, AppRoutes.saticilarRoute.route);

// with
(child.key as GlobalKey<NavigatorState>).currentState.pushNamed(AppRoutes.saticilarRoute.route)
```

[Persisting AppBar Drawer across all Pages Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659805/persisting-appbar-drawer-across-all-pages-flutter#answer-53920491)

or you can use a navigation key, check out this.
[How to navigate without context in flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962112/how-to-navigate-without-context-in-flutter-app)

Even better is to put navigation bar in a separate file and reuse that if needed. Remove builder and use `home/initialRoute`.

Comment: I added this to MyApp class ->     home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(),
      ),          but I got the same error